# How to best use Enums with database lookup tables for readable code

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-core, ef-code-first

I like to define Enums for my static, data shaping properties of my objects. For example, status and type columns I always like to have defined in an enum with a name and a long form description like this:

```
        public enum TordDocumentDocumentTypes
    {
        [System.ComponentModel.Description("Annual Meeting Notice or Materials")]
        AnnualMeeting = 1,
        [System.ComponentModel.Description("Annual Formula Rate Posting")]
        AnnualFormulaRate =2 
    }
```

I also like to then turn these enums into something that can be persited into a lookup table. I tend to let the code do the "driving" here. Meaning that I don't let the lookups change from the DB side, instead I make it so the code changes the lookup. I'll often have a function somewhere on a app page to do this.

Does anyone have a better way that they perform these common functions of capturing status and types?

Comment: "Code first" might be droid you are looking for. | I added the tag, as I am not that fluent in ths area.

Comment: Points for a well used pop culture reference. If only more people used them with this level of class.

Answer (score 1):

**Querying with EntityFramework:**

It should support what you are trying to accomplish.

https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework5/enum-in-entity-framework5.aspx

**Querying with ADO.NET:**

If you are using ADO.NET you can cast the the status value representation coming back from the database into an enum (vice versa for inserts). You could accomplish this by creating an extension method for an integer. This could be called when creating your DTO collection.

**Heres A Code Example:**

```
public enum Status : int
{
    Unknown = 0,
    Shipped = 1,
    Pending = 2,
    BackOrdered = 3, 
}

public class DatabaseRecord
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Item { get; set; }
    public int OrderStatus { get; set; }
}

public class DTO
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Item { get; set; }
    public Status OrderStatus { get; set; }         
}

class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<DatabaseRecord> Database = new List<DatabaseRecord>()
        {
            new DatabaseRecord(){ ID = 1, Item = "Socks",   OrderStatus = 1},
            new DatabaseRecord(){ ID = 1, Item = "Shoes",   OrderStatus = 2},
            new DatabaseRecord(){ ID = 1, Item = "TShirt",  OrderStatus = 11}
        };

        List<DTO> DTOCollection = Database.Select(x => new DTO{
            ID = x.ID,
            Item = x.Item,
            OrderStatus = x.OrderStatus.ToEnum<Status>(Status.Unknown)               
        }).ToList();

        foreach(var memberOfDTO in DTOCollection)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{ memberOfDTO.OrderStatus }");
        }
    }
}

public static class Extenstions
{
    public static T ToEnum<T>(this int integer, T defaultValue)  where T : struct, IConvertible
    {                        
        if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(T), integer))
        {
            return (T)Enum.Parse(defaultValue.GetType(), integer.ToString());
        }
        return Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
    }
}
```

**Output:**
[Screenshot Of Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09CGe.png)

```
Shipped
Pending
Unknown
```

Comment: I feel like you can make you answer even more helpful by providing code samples.

Comment: @VladimirGrichina you are right, here's an example if you dont want to leverage entity framework.